# How to Mock AWS Lambda invoke

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, mocha.js

I have the following common.js code.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.callNextLambda = function callNextLambda(lambdaName, payload) {
  const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
  lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: lambdaName,
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: payload,
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);
  });
}
```

I tried to mock above as,

```
it('MockAWS.mock should mock Lambda invoke', () => {
  const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
  AWSMock.mock(lambda, 'invoke', (params, callback) => {
    const awsResponse = {
      LogResult:'some-data',
      Payload:'{\'contentType\':\'text/plain\',\'message\':\'some-other-data\',\'status\':200}',
      StatusCode:200
    };
    callback(null, awsResponse);
  })

});
```

The above code is throwing some weird error. And not covering the lines in code coverage. I am very much new to NodeJS. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used [mock-aws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-aws) before, but it looks like you're calling it wrong.

Change this:

```
AWSMock.mock(lambda, 'invoke', (params, callback) => {
  // logic here
})
```

to this:

```
AWSMock.mock('lambda', 'invoke', (params, callback) => {
  // logic here as normal
})
```

The first parameter must be a string.